# Correct Syntax for getting the sum of a matrix - Octave

Tags: matrix, sum, octave

I am taking Andrew Ng's class on Machine Learning and within implementing a Regularized Cost Function for a Neural Network, we have to calculate:

[image]

Simply put, ignoring the bias units (the first column), we have to get the sum of all the elements of the matrix squared.

This is the code that I tried writing:

```
reg_theta1 = Theta1(:,2:end);
reg_theta2 = Theta2(:,2:end);
sum_theta1 = sum(sum(reg_theta1.^2 ,2));
sum_theta2 = sum(sum(reg_theta2.^2 ,2));

J = J + (lambda/2*m)*(sum_theta1 + sum_theta2);
```

However, I found online a similar answer:

```
penalty = (lambda/(2*m))*(sum(sum(Theta1(:, 2:end).^2, 2)) + sum(sum(Theta2(:,2:end).^2, 2)));
J = J + penalty;
```

And that did return the correct result.
The logic is precisely the same, so there must a mistake in my syntax, but I simply can't find it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is more efficient to do `sum(reg_theta1(:).^2)` than `sum(sum(reg_theta1.^2 ,2))`.

Comment: Please don't add the solution to the question, this is what the green tick mark next to the approved answer does. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(lambda/2*m)` = `(lambda/2)*m` ≠ `(lambda/(2*m))`

Comment: these are identical in octave  (are they not in matlab?)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Yes. Exactly that is the problem. Try the above code with `m=1; lambda=1;`

Comment: ah, I didn't even read the question xD

Comment: It was actually (lamba/(2*m)).
They weren't calculating m in the denominator.

Comment: @ShaulSolomon its your code that is wrong, not the one you found around